# Trouble returning result-set from Oracle into MS Access

Tags: oracle, ms-access, stored-procedures, oracle11g

In my ongoing journey of transitioning my knowledge from DB2 to Oracle, I 'm having a hard time doing something in Oracle that I was able to easily accomplish in DB2. I'm sure I'm missing something easy, but I'm not seeing it.

In DB2, when I called a stored procedure that returned a result-set, I just called the proc with its input parameters.

e.g.
 call MyProcWithNoInputParms ();

The result-set automatically returned into whatever client called the proc.

Calling the proc from within Microsoft Access works exactly the same. the result-set automatically comes back into Access.

It's my understanding that when calling an Oracle proc that returns a result-set, the result-set is included in the parameter-list as a variable of type "refCursor".

```
e.g.
var rc refCursor;
exec MySchema.MyProcWithNoInputParms (:rc);
```

That works beautifully if I run from within Oracle, and I confirmed that the result-set is being returned correctly, but when I try to put that inside a Microsoft Access pass-through query, it throws an error saying:

ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

I'm pretty sure the ODBC data-source is correct. Since it throws an Oracle error, it must be actually connecting to Oracle.

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, you don't show any relevant code, so who knows?

Comment: I would suggest you delete the pass-though query, and re-link. (re-create) the pass-though query.

Comment: Albert, I deleted the pass-through query, and I recreated it, but I still get the same problem: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement. It did ask me for my Oracle user-name and password first, so I'm pretty sure that it's connecting to Oracle.

OldProgrammer - those two lines are the entirety of my MS Access code.

The stored procedure looks like this:

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MYSCHEMA.MyProcWithNoInputParms(mycursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)  
     IS  
     BEGIN  
        OPEN mycursor FOR  
           SELECT c.thisColumn,  
                  c.thatColumn,  
                  c.createdTimestamp,  
                  c.createdBy,  
                  NVL(c.statusString, 'Defined') statusString  
             FROM MyTable c  
           ORDER by c.thisColumn;  
     
     END;
     /`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting of that. I'm having a hard time with getting markdown to work correctly.

Comment: Based on a suggestion, I changed the way I'm calling the stored-proc in the Access query:  

    var rc refCursor;  
    begin  
    MySchema.MyProcWithNoInputParms (:rc);  
    end;  

I tried that exact thing from within SQL-Plus, SQL Developer, and Toad, and it worked beautifully in all three environments. But, when I use that method inside a pass-through ODBC query from MS Access, I still get an error-message that says, "ORA-0090: invalid SQL Statement".  

It can't be that uncommon to return an Oracle result-set into MS Access. How do most people accomplish this sort of thing?

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out? I too would like to know.

Comment: Wilson - see below

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting around this by changing my stored-procedure to insert the results into a table instead of returning a result-set. My Access database calls the stored procedure to populate the table. Then, another Access query returns the results from that table using a simple pass-through query.

It's not quite as "elegant" as my previous method, but I've been doing this long enough to know that it doesn't have to be pretty to get the job done. :-)

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a more elegant solution?

Comment: No. I settled for the less-elegant (but functional) solution.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for responding.